# Kubernetes client python API error 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I´m trying create a Python client to connect and exec a command in a pod on AKS Cluster, however when try connect i get message error from my client 401 Unauthorized.Has anyone experienced this problem in the API?

**API EXCEPTION MESSAGE:**

```
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'ba23c2b3-d65b-4200-b802-161300119860', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Mon, 21 Sep 2020 18:21:59 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

**Python Client API Kubernetes**

```
    from __future__ import print_function
import time
import kubernetes.client
import os
from kubernetes.stream import stream
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint


name = input("Insira o POD name cadastrado")
namespace = input("namespace do POD cadastrado")
NomeAtuador = input("Insira o nome do atuador a ser gerado o arquivo de configuração")


configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
#configuration.verify_ssl=False
#configuration.assert_hostname = False
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = 'MYTOKEN'
configuration.ssl_ca_cert= 'PATH TO CA.CRT'
configuration.host = "HOST_IP:443"

api_instance = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(
    kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration))


exec_command = [
            '/etc/openvpn/setup/newClientCert.sh',
            (NomeAtuador), 
            'xxxxxxx']

resp = stream(api_instance.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec(
    (name), (namespace), command=exec_command,
              stderr=True, stdin=True,
              stdout=True, tty=True))
print("Response: " + resp)
```

I´m using a **Python 3.8.2** and **Kubernetes 1.16.13**

Comment: Did you add correct token? You can retrieve it by using  `config.load_kube_config()` and then `kubernetes.client.configuration.Configuration._default.api_key`

Comment: Hi @MariuszK.! sorry for the delay.

The token is right, probably some RBAC rule are dropping the request.

To Work Arround the problem, i needed add the following configuration to cluster config.

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-cluster-admin \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --group=system:serviceaccounts`

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer- it might be helpful for others who encounter similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve my problem i add the following configuration to cluster config.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-cluster-admin \   --clusterrole=cluster-admin \   --group=system:serviceaccounts
```